# What is the correct nginx configuration for a WordPress multisite setup using subdirectories?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite, subdirectory

I've converted an older WordPress installation to a multisite setup using subdirectories. I'm using nginx + php5-fpm on Debian stable. The setup has worked for years.

I went from domain.tld as a single WordPress blog to a new setup where domain.tld is still the main WP site on the multisite network but I have two new WP installations at domain.tld/asite and domain.tld/bsite. Everything on domain.tld still works and I can get to posts at domain.tld/asite/post1, but: I can't get the blog homepage at domain.tld/asite to display. The server returns a 404 error.

My question is this: How do I get domain.tld/asite to show me the blog posts that exist? What's a clean nginx server block example for this setup? I suspect there's a rewrite rule missing or mixing things up in my config...

Just to be clear: the domain.tld installation has no pages, categories or tags that conflict with /asite.

**Edit:** I forgot something... If I turn pretty permalinks off on the asite installation, then domain.tld/asite works, but the individual blog posts can't be reached anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. My nginx config was correct all along. The trick is to set the Siteurl and Home fields in the network admin for /asite to the exact same URLs.